# After upgrading to Magento version 2.2.3 the following errors are shown when running the php bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy command

Tags: magento2.2.3

> ## frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2304/2304
>
> ======== 100% %  1 min frontend/Dws/customtheme/en_US        2218/2378           ====================
>   ======>- 93% %   1 min C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\magento\framework\App\View\Asse
>   t\Publisher.php(73):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\magento\framework\App\View\Asse
>   t\Publisher.php(61):
>   Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publishAsset(Ob
>   ject(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\magento\module-deploy\Service\D
>   eployStaticFile.php(89):
>   Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publish(Obj
>   ect(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\magento\module-deploy\Service\D
>   eployPackage.php(189):
>   Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticFile->deployFile('css/
>   local-m.les...', Array) 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\magento\module-deploy\Service\D
>   eployPackage.php(136):
>   Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->processFile(Object(
>   Magento\Deploy\Package\PackageFile),
>   Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package)) 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\magento\module-deploy\Service\D
>   eployPackage.php(107):
>   Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deployEmulated(Obje
>   ct(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array, false) [internal function]:
>   Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->Magento\Deploy\Ser
>   vice{closure}()
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\magento\framework\App\State.php (186):
>   call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\magento\module-deploy\Service\D
>   eployPackage.php(108):
>   Magento\Framework\App\State->emulateAreaCode('frontend',
>   Object(Closure)) 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\magento\module-deploy\Process\Q
>   ueue.php(281):
>   Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deploy(Object(Magento\Deplo
>   y\Package\Package), Array) 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\magento\module-deploy\Process\
>   Queue.php(200):
>   Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->execute(Object(Magento\Deploy\Pack
>   age\Package)) 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\magento\module-deploy\Process\
>   Queue.php(162):
>   Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->assertAndExecute('frontend/Dws/di. ..',
>   Array, Array) 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\magento\module-deploy\Strategy
>   \QuickDeploy.php(76): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->process() 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\magento\module-deploy\Service\
>   DeployStaticContent.php(109):
>   Magento\Deploy\Strategy\QuickDeploy->deploy(Array)
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Console\Comma
>   nd\DeployStaticContentCommand.php(140):
>   Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticConte nt->deploy(Array) 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Comman
>   d.php(242):
>   Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand->execute(Ob
>   ject(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Consol e\Output\ConsoleOutput)) 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\symfony\console\Application.ph p(843):
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\
>   Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput) ) 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\symfony\console\Application.ph p(193):
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Setup
>   \Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\I nput\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.
>   php(104):
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\
>   Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput) )
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\vendor\symfony\console\Application.ph p(117):
>   Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\In
>   put\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\discount\bin\magento(23): Symfony\Component\Co
>   nsole\Application->run() {main}
>   ←[1A←[2K←[1A←[2K←[1A←[2K←[1A←[2Kfrontend/Magento/blank/en_US
>   2288/228 8           ============================ 100% %  1 min
>
> ## adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         2907/2907
>
> ======== 100% %  1 min frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2304/2304           ====================
>   ======== 100% %  1 min frontend/Dws/customtheme/en_US        2297/2378           ====================
>   =======> 96% %   1 min ←[1A←[2K←[1A←[2K←[1A←[2K←[1A←[2Kfrontend/Magento/blank/en_US
>   2288/228 8           ============================ 100% %  1 min
>
> ## adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         2907/2907
>
> ======== 100% %  1 min frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2304/2304           ====================
>   ======== 100% %  1 min frontend/Dws/customtheme/en_US        2334/2378           ====================
>   =======> 98% %   1 min ←[1A←[2K←[1A←[2K←[1A←[2K←[1A←[2Kfrontend/Magento/blank/en_US
>   2288/228 8           ============================ 100% %  1 min
>
> ## adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         2907/2907
>
> ======== 100% %  1 min frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2304/2304           ====================
>   ======== 100% %  1 min frontend/Dws/customtheme/en_US        2371/2378           ====================
>   =======> 99% %   1 min ←[1A←[2K←[1A←[2K←[1A←[2K←[1A←[2Kfrontend/Magento/blank/en_US
>   2288/228 8           ============================ 100% %  1 min
>
> ## adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         2907/2907
>
> ======== 100% %  1 min frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2304/2304           ====================
>   ======== 100% %  1 min frontend/Dws/customtheme/en_US        2378/2378           ====================
>   ======== 100% %  1 min
>
> [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]   Cannot read
>   contents from file "C:/xampp/htdocs/discount/pub/
>   static/frontend/Dws/customtheme/en_US/css/local-m.css"
>   Warning!file_get_c
>   ontents(C:/xampp/htdocs/discount/pub/static/frontend/Dws/disc
>   ountwater/en_US/css/local-m.css): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or di   rectory
>
> setup:static-content:deploy [-f|--force] [-s|--strategy [STRATEGY]]
>   [-a|--area [ AREA]] [--exclude-area [EXCLUDE-AREA]] [-t|--theme
>   [THEME]] [--exclude-theme [EX CLUDE-THEME]] [-l|--language [LANGUAGE]]
>   [--exclude-language [EXCLUDE-LANGUAGE]]  [-j|--jobs [JOBS]]
>   [--symlink-locale] [--content-version CONTENT-VERSION] [--re
>   fresh-content-version-only] [--no-javascript] [--no-css] [--no-less]
>   [--no-image s] [--no-fonts] [--no-html] [--no-misc] [--no-html-minify]
>   [--] []...

Comment: Is there any empty theme in your application?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/j3qdwf
Please check my theme

Comment: No, there is no empty theme.